# Pandas dropna() would not work for a filtered data

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nan

The following code downloads Close price data for the list of tickers in "tickers".   My objective is to get a new list called "valid_tickers" which meet my criteria - in this example, criteria is that a ticker has more than 1,323 data points.

In other words, I want to eliminate stocks that have a shorter price history (FTV in this example).  If I apply dropna() to the entire data, all the n/a are eliminated but I am also shortening the price history of the stock that has full data (MSFT in this example).

This is undesirable.  Therefore, I want to eliminate n/a just for the ticker where they are found, then measure the length of its price history, and include the ticker in the "valid_tickers" list only if it has more than 1,323 points.  However, dropna() does not want to work on data[ticker] for some reason.   What am I doing wrong here?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['FTV','MSFT']

data = yf.download(tickers, start="2012-04-03", end="2017-07-07")['Close']
data = data.reset_index()

valid_tickers =[]

for ticker in tickers:
    data[ticker] = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [ticker])
    data[ticker] = data[ticker].dropna()
    if len(data[ticker]) > 1323:
        valid_tickers.append(ticker)

print (valid_tickers)
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of `data` and and example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a problem with the re-use of the name `data`. What would happen if you replaced `data[ticker]` with `tmp` ?

```
tickers = ['FTV','MSFT']

data = yf.download(tickers, start="2012-04-03", end="2017-07-07")['Close']
data = data.reset_index()

valid_tickers =[]

for ticker in tickers:
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [ticker])
    tmp = tmp.dropna()
    if len(tmp) > 1323:
        valid_tickers.append(ticker)

print (valid_tickers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to find the tickers with more than 1323 valid price observations? If so, use this:

```
valid_obs_series = data.notnull().sum() # get total non-na observations per ticker
valid_tickers = list(valid_obs_series[valid_obs_series > 1323].index) # get valid tickers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in one line with `df.dropna()`:

```py
# your code:
tickers = ['FTV','MSFT']
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers, start="2012-04-03", end="2017-07-07")['Close']
data = data.reset_index()
valid_tickers =[]

# my addition:
valid_tickers.append(data.dropna(thresh=1323, axis=1).columns[1:][0]) # this line here
```

It appends the columns names of stocks that have `> 1323` valid data points to the `valid_tickers` list. In your case, only 'MSFT'.